# Multiple required value for a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables : **champions, roles, champs_to_roles**

The champs_to_roles table looks like this :

```
|ID_champ|ID_role|
 ----------------
|       2|      2|
|       4|      5|
|       5|      3|
|       3|      2|
|       1|      1|
|       1|      2|
```

I'm trying to SELECT the ID_champ WHERE ID_role = 1 AND ID_role = 2.

At this point I have the following code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `c`.`name`
FROM `champions` AS c,
(
    SELECT `ID_champ`
    FROM `champs_to_roles`
    WHERE `ID_role` IN(1,2)
) AS r
WHERE `r`.`ID_champ` = `c`.`ID`
```

However, this returns me ID_champ with ID_role = 1 OR Id_role = 2 OR both of them

How can I fetch what I need ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two inner joins to the association table - one for each role type:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM champions c
JOIN champs_to_roles ctr1 ON ctr1.ID_champ = c.id AND ctr1.ID_role = 1
JOIN champs_to_roles ctr2 ON ctr2.ID_champ = c.id AND ctr2.ID_role = 2
```

By using a *inner* join, *both* rows in `champs_to_roles` must exist for the champion to be returned.

The DISTINCT keyword was dispensed with because you don't need it (unless you have duplicate entries in your association table, which seems unlikely and a bad design if even possible)

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. Your solution is very flexible if I have to increase the number of required values ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with the solution by Bohemian, but for completeness there is also the possibility to use a count and check the number of roles returned from a subselect

```
SELECT c.name
FROM champions AS c
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID_champ, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_role) AS NumRole
    FROM champs_to_roles
    WHERE ID_role IN(1,2)
    GROUP BY ID_champ
) AS r 
ON r.ID_champ = c.ID AND NumRole = 2
```

(this could also be done without the subselect but it would be a touch less readable when you are not returning the columns that you need to group by, etc)

Comment: @Bohemian, @Kickstart, thanks for your answer. This works pretty good. I found myself this solution :

    `SELECT DISTINCT c.name
     FROM champions AS c,
 (
          SELECT ID_champ
   FROM champs_to_roles
   WHERE ID_role IN(1,2)
          GROUP BY ID_champ
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
 ) AS r
     WHERE r.ID_champ = c.ID`

Comment: That will do it, although I prefer to user the contemporary join syntax. I used COUNT(DISTINCT ID_role) just in case ID_role is not unique for champions, although if it is unique (ie, there is a unique covering index over ID_champ and ID_role) you can just use COUNT(*). But I do prefer the method suggested by @Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Select 
    c.name
from
    champions c
where
    exists( select 
            1
        from
            champs_to_roles ctr1
        where
            ctr1.ID_champ = c.ID
                and exists( select 
                    1
                from
                    champs_to_roles ctr2
                where
                    ctr2.ID_champ = ctr1.ID_champ
                        and ctr2.ID_role <> ctr1.ID_role))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name
FROM champions AS c,
(
    SELECT c1.ID_champ
    FROM champs_to_roles c1, champs_to_roles c2
    WHERE c1.ID_role=1 and c2.ID_role=2 
    AND c1.ID_champ=c2.ID_champ
) AS r
WHERE r.ID_champ = c.ID
```